# CSS grayscale filter suddenly stopped working

Tags: css, image, webkit, grayscale

Recently the Grayscacle effect on my website (DezinoGraphist.com) suddenly stopped working. The CSS code added a grayscale effect to all the items of a particular section (association) until you hovered over them, then the items became regularly colored.

It worked perfectly for quite some time but now has suddenly stopped working. I did not change anything. Following is the CSS code for reference:

```
img.grayscale{
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* For Webkit browsers */
filter: gray; /* For IE 6 - 9 */
-webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
}

img.grayscale:hover{
filter: grayscale(0%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

Hope this is something very minor.

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try to put somewhere in html filter svg:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <filter id='grayscale'>
    <feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

And then in your css just use filter id:

```
filter: url('#grayscale');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Devian. Putting SVG filter did the trick. It worked :)